# Rules for algebra equations involving modulo operations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

While working on a menial task in front of a clock today I was distracting myself by proving that all three hands only align twice a day.  That lead me to wonder how one would deal with more complex problems involving modulo arithmetic.  I know several rules for reducing equations involving all sorts of operators from simple addition up through very complex triple integrals and the like.  But, I never learned any rules for manipulating the modulo operator.

What are valid operations that can be used to reduce equataions involving multiple modulo operators?

Comment: Are you familiar with [rings,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) and [fields,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) and that the integers mod $\rm\:m\:$ for a ring, and a field if $\rm\:m\:$ is prime?

Comment: Gems, for the sake of argument, lets say I'm not.  I actually wandered into set theory a little when I was learning Haskell, but I really only know enough to be dangerous.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are some examples I can think of.

Let $m$ be any natural number, and let $a,b,c,d$ be any integers. Then:

- $\equiv$ modulo $m$ is an equivalence relation. That is,

  - $a\equiv a\bmod m$.
  - If $a\equiv b\bmod m$, then $b\equiv a\bmod m$.
  - If $a\equiv b\bmod m$ and $b\equiv c\bmod m$, then $a\equiv c\bmod m$.
- Addition and multiplication are well-defined modulo $m$. That is,

  - If $a\equiv b\bmod m$ and $c\equiv d\bmod m$, then $a+c\equiv b+d\bmod m$, and $ac\equiv bd\bmod m$.
- If $ac\equiv bc\bmod mc$, then $a\equiv b\bmod m$.
- The congruence $ax\equiv b\bmod m$ has solutions (i.e., integers $x$ making the statement true) if and only if $\gcd(a,m)$ divides $b$.

You also have

- If $p$ is a prime and $1\leq k\leq p-1$, then the binomial coefficient $\mathopen{\big(}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{p}{k}\mathclose{\big)}$ satisfies $\mathopen{\big(}\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{p}{k}\mathclose{\big)}\equiv 0\bmod p$.
- [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), and its generalization, [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)
- There are [primitive roots modulo $m$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) if and only if $m=p^k$ or $m=2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime number, or if $m=2$ or $m=4$.
- [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)
- [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)
- [Quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) (more advanced)